# Object does not allow properties to be added or changed - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building a Google script to interact with Drive and Sheets. When running the code below, I get an error upon executing

"log.getActiveSheet().getRange(log.getLastRow(),2).setValue = date;"

that states "Object does not allow properties to be added or changed." I can not figure out why.

Does anyone have any insight?

```
function setUp() { 
  Logger.log("Starting setUp()");
  var user = Session.getActiveUser();
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("ChangeAlert_Log");
  Logger.log(files.hasNext());
  var log;
  if(files.hasNext() == false){
    Logger.log("creating log file now...");
    log = SpreadsheetApp.create("ChangeAlert_Log");
    log.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue("file_names");
    log.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 2).setValue("file_dates");
    return log;
  } else{
    Logger.log("Found Log...trying to open");
    var logFile = files.next();
    var url = logFile.getUrl()
    log = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    log.addEditor(user);
    Logger.log("returning setUp()");
    return log;
  }
}

function IDfiles(){
  Logger.log("running IDfiles()");  
  var log = setUp()
  var user = Session.getActiveUser();
  var user_files = DriveApp.getFiles(); //returns a FileIterator Object
  var i = 0;
  var file;

  while(user_files.hasNext()){
    file = user_files.next();
    if(file.isStarred()){
      var date = file.getLastUpdated();
      Logger.log("Date: " + date);
      //file_dates[i] = date;
      log.getActiveSheet().getRange(log.getLastRow(),2).setValue = date;
      var fileName = file.getName();
      Logger.log("File: " + fileName);
      log.getActiveSheet().getRange(log.getLastRow(), 1).setValue = fileName;
      //file_names[i] = fileName;
      i++;
      Logger.log("i= " + i);
    }
  }  

  Logger.log("returning IDfiles()");
  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the log object from your function, get the newly created spreadsheet ID instead and return that.

```
var log = SpreadsheetApp.create("some log");
return log.getId();
```

and then once returned get the sheet again by ID.